# Order by A then B using Ruby on Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, activerecord

This is not a homework question. I am trying to learn more.

I have the following entities with attributes 
`Manufacturer {name}` //Store Manufactueres
`Model {manufacturer_id, name}` //Store Models
`Tint {manufacturer_id, model_id, front, side, rear}` //Store measurements

I have the follow data in my `Tint` entity. Alphabets stands for different manufacturer name and models.

```
Manufacturer | Model | Front | Side | Rear | 
-------------+-------+-------+------+-------
A            | AD    | 10    | 10   | 10   |
B            | AB    | 10    | 10   | 10   |
A            | AA    | 10    | 10   | 10   |
A            | AC    | 10    | 10   | 10   |
B            | AA    | 10    | 10   | 10   |
A            | AB    | 10    | 10   | 10   |
```

When I print it out in `view`, I would like to have it sorted based on `Manufacturer` name and then `Model`. So the result will be as below. The name of the Manufactures will be sorted alphabetically, then Models.

```
Manufacturer | Model | Front | Side | Rear | 
-------------+-------+-------+------+-------
A            | AA    | 10    | 10   | 10   |
A            | AB    | 10    | 10   | 10   |
A            | AC    | 10    | 10   | 10   |
A            | AD    | 10    | 10   | 10   |
B            | AA    | 10    | 10   | 10   |
B            | AB    | 10    | 10   | 10   |
```

I have setup the model to make sure `Manufacturer` and `Model` is a distinct pair of values.

My question is since I am referencing using `manufacturer_id` and `model_id`, how can I get the name of the `Manufacturer` and `Model` from `Manufacturer` and `Model` table.

In my tints_controller.rb, I have `@tints = Tint.all.order(:manufacturer_id)`. However, it will only sort based on the `manufacturer_id` (as in numbers) instead of the name of the manufacturer.

I know that I can do it in SQL way `(SELECT, FROM, WHERE)` in RoR model. However, I would like to know is it possible to use ActiveRecord to sort the data based on their name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my question:

In `tints_controller.rb`, I wrote 
`@tints = Tint.joins(:manufacturer, :model).order("manufacturers.name ASC, models.name ASC")` to join the table and order them accordingly.

I tried the answer provided by @Goston above and I had an issue when I was trying edit the `tints`. It did not allow me to edit.

Note: Answer provided by @Goston will order them, but it broke the `edit` function for my case.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you have 3 models, Tint, Manufacturer and Model. I am assuming you have the appropiate has_many and belongs_to [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) setup correctly.

```
Tint.rb
belongs_to :workspace

Manufacturer.rb
has_many :models
has_many :tints,  through: :models

Model.rb:
belongs_to Manufacturer
has_many :tints
```

You need to first join the three models together, and then order by some criteria

```
tints_controller.rb
@tints = Tint.joins(model: :manufacturer).order('manufacturers.name, models.name').pluck('manufacturers.name, models.name, tints.front, tints.side, tints.rear')
```

That will give you all tints records and they appropiate models and manufacturers.

Comment: Yes, you understand the question correctly and I have the following relationships in my model. However, I'm trying to avoid using SQL join.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you have the `id` of an entity in Rails, you can easily retrieve other associated fields simply by instantiating that entity:

```
@manufacturer = Manufacturer.find(params[manufacturer_id])
```

Then it's a simple matter to retrieve any of the other fields:

```
@manufacturer_name = @manufacturer.name
```

If you need a collection of manufacturers or manufacturer names, then it's advisable to build yourself an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object immediately via a scoped query (as you already know). I have no idea what your criteria are, otherwise, I'd supply some sample code. I can tell you that your scoped query should include an `.order` clause at the end:

```
@manufacturers = Manufacturer.where("some_column = ?", some_criterion).order(:sort_field)
```

In the above example, `:sort_field` would be the field by you want to sort your `ActiveRecord::Relation`. I'm guessing in your case, it's `:name`.

All this having been said, if you want fancy sorted tables, you should look into the [JQuery DataTables](https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails) gem. DataTables can do a lot of the heavy lifting for you, and it's convenient for your users because they can then sort and resort by any column you present.

Comment: I totally get what you are trying to say but I am somewhat lost. I know that I can do `@manufacturer.name` to get the name of the manufacturer. Since I am in `Tint` controller, how can I implant the following code by altering`@tints = Tint.all.order(:manufacturer_id)`. I was trying to figure that out in the last hour, but I am still lost.

Answer (score 0):

In your tints_controller.rb, instedad of

```
@tints = Tint.all.order(:manufacturer_id)
```

please write:

```
@tints = Tint.all.order(:manufacturer_id, :model_id)
```

Comment: I tried this yesterday, this does not work as it will only sort the ID instead of the name of the model and manufacturer.